# What is best hardware solution for sending sms?

Tags: sms, gsm, modem

I have a task to create production system for sending sms, for approximetly 10 000- 20 000 in a day. Our company have an agreement with local  provider, and have multiple SIM card. I'm looking for 3g modems or some hardware (like GoIP) but i need very stable and quick solution. 
What could you advise? 
GoIP is cool, but isn't stable enough.

Answer (score 0):

if you will use the chip to send msn try wit this service
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

Comment: My local provider give me price ~0.02 Dollar per sms via SIM card. twilio give 0.065. It is 20 000 dollars monthly different...

Comment: If you have agreement with local provider, why they don't simply give you access for bulk messages via their API, or SMPP access to SMSC ?

Comment: I don't really know. The legal part of this project was in responsible of legal department. I also asked if there a way to have somekind of API or web service to send sms via our provider, but they told that no, our agreement allow us to send sms via SIM card and GSM modems with no  limit, and web service will cost much more, so, i'm trying to solve problem  with that information that i have.

Comment: well, i thing have two option, 
1- you will search, to  buy some product or service ..
2- .or you can create a app on device, to open a port, and listen from device,  like  a web socket, you could try to create an app with soket.io, and send message by server to client

Comment: With what device? This was my question - what device to use. Most GSM modem are quite slow for sending big amount of sms... someone told that there is quick modems, but i couldn't find any info about it